# Batch Renaming in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a full list of files like,

```
    1066_Hasoffers.apk.apk.txt        
    161_Genesys.apk.apk.txt        
    231_Attendance.apk.apk.txt  
    2956_BookingBug.apk.apk.txt  
    3394_sumall.apk.apk.txt   
    4306_Vocus.apk.apk.txt     
    .....
```

And I would like a one-liner to rename them to (say).

```
       1066_Hasoffers.txt        
        161_Genesys.txt        
        231_Attendance.txt  
        2956_BookingBug.txt  
        3394_sumall.txt   
        4306_Vocus.txt     
        ....
```

How can i get this done ?

Comment: I am not certain what you are asking.  If you want a command or small script to rename all the files in a directory that fits a certain pattern, please say so.  Otherwise, please make this question clear what you are looking for.  It will also help if you can describe what you have tried so far (for example, if you have looked at the find command and don't understand it, say so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rename` command can be used:

```
rename 's/apk.apk.//' *.txt
```

which will remove `apk.apk` from your file names.

Or you can a use loop in bash:

```
for i in *.txt; do
 new=${i%apk.apk.txt}txt
 mv "${i}" "${new}"
done
```